# How to package play solution as jar ( like a dll in C#) for other play solutions can use it?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework

I'm very new to Play-framework and Java and Eclipse. I have this scenario where I should be able to provide this application as a jar/package.

In short I want to Package (MVC + JS + Images) as a Play Module
So that, other play applications should be able to use this package/jar in their pages

Its like, i'm building an app which as custom UI controls and want to anybody to use it.Any recommendations, examples or help are highly appreciated!

Thank you..

Comment: Any pluggable architecture suggestion for Play framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Play modules](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Modules), which contains a link to a blog post showing how to create a Play module.